read nested json inside csv file using pandas?
I have a csv file that with rows that looks like this:
745198;2024-09-10 10:09:10.7;leaf-2;{"Accelerometer": {"X": 0.055297852, "Y": 0.993530273, "Z": 0.000244141}}
745199;2024-09-10 10:09:10.71;leaf-2;{"Accelerometer": {"X": 0.056274414, "Y": 0.994384766, "Z": 0.000976563}}
745200;2024-09-10 10:09:10.721;leaf-2;{"Accelerometer": {"X": 0.055786133, "Y": 0.994018555, "Z": 0.000854492}}
745201;2024-09-10 10:09:10.732;leaf-2;{"Accelerometer": {"X": 0.055053711, "Y": 0.993530273, "Z": 0.000854492}}

and I would like to read this data into a dataframe, and somehow get the 3 accelerometer data into separate columns, but I haven't been able to figure out a good way of doing this.
I have searched for similar cases Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas
But none of the suggested solutions seems to work.
I can create a for loop and manually extract the information I need line by line, but I'm guessing there should be a nice fast way of doing this that I just do not know of.

The clever automated tools are great when your data fits the model.  When you have data that doesn't fit, you go back to doing it line by line.  This shouldn't to hard to handle in a loop.

That was also my solution, but I just figured that the structure I had looked like something fairly standard, so I was guessing there was a standard method that would work on it.

you should really consider not using csv as a serialization format. What is creating this csv?

@juanpa.arrivillaga This is not something I can control, I am merely given the data from an external source in this format.

First convert the JSON string in the 'Accelerometer' column to a dictionary:
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', header=None, names=['ID', 'Timestamp', 'Device', 'Accelerometer'])

df['Accelerometer'] = df['Accelerometer'].apply(json.loads)

Then normalize the 'Accelerometer' column to separate columns:
accelerometer_df = pd.json_normalize(df['Accelerometer'])
accelerometer_df.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

Finally concatenate the original DataFrame with the new accelerometer columns:
result_df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['Accelerometer']), accelerometer_df], axis=1)
print(result_df)

The output:
       ID                Timestamp  Device         X         Y         Z
0  745198    2024-09-10 10:09:10.7  leaf-2  0.055298  0.993530  0.000244
1  745199   2024-09-10 10:09:10.71  leaf-2  0.056274  0.994385  0.000977
2  745200  2024-09-10 10:09:10.721  leaf-2  0.055786  0.994019  0.000854
3  745201  2024-09-10 10:09:10.732  leaf-2  0.055054  0.993530  0.000854


That worked beautifully, thank you

You can do this entirely in pandas as per the answer from @m-sarabi
However, if you want something that's more efficient then you could just process the source file using basic Python techniques then finally build your dataframe from the objects you've created (a list of dictionaries).
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

SOURCE = Path("foo.csv")

data = []
with SOURCE.open() as source:
    for t in map(lambda x: x.split(";"), source):
        d = dict(zip("ABC", t[:-1]))
        d.update(loads(t[-1])["Accelerometer"])
        data.append(d)

print(pd.DataFrame(data))

Output:
        A                        B       C         X         Y         Z
0  745198    2024-09-10 10:09:10.7  leaf-2  0.055298  0.993530  0.000244
1  745199   2024-09-10 10:09:10.71  leaf-2  0.056274  0.994385  0.000977
2  745200  2024-09-10 10:09:10.721  leaf-2  0.055786  0.994019  0.000854
3  745201  2024-09-10 10:09:10.732  leaf-2  0.055054  0.993530  0.000854

